# Big O of binomial coefficient

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

I found a question online, but I can't figure out a way to prove that

\begin{align} \begin{pmatrix} n \newline
\frac n2\end{pmatrix}= O(2^n) \end{align}

Is there an easy way to proof this?

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you applied Stirling's approximation?

Comment: this is trivial because $\sum_k {n\choose k}=2^n$. did you actually want to show that ${n\choose n/2}\sim 2^{n}$?

Comment: @MikeHawk: It isn’t: $$\binom{2n}n\sim\frac{4^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}\;.$$ I’ll guess that the trivial solution is intended.

Comment: @MikeHawk thanks, I haven't considered trying this formula, but it makes this question kind of trivial :) 
I was kind of stuck trying to use the Stirling's approximation, but it didn't work out (@angryavian)

Comment: $\binom{n}{n/2}\sim\frac{2^{n+1}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}}$ according to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/486381/721644) answer. There is also a [related](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/172126/721644) problem involving the application.

Comment: I'm not sure if your question counts as a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/674533/721644)

Comment: @angryavian: Stirling is overkill here. See Mike's comment.

Comment: Maybe this [(dis)prove: $n!=O\left(2^n\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/930326/721644)?

Comment: [Show that $2^{n+1}$ is $O(2^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2612966/721644)

Comment: I guess by $O(2^n)$ they mean $\Theta(2^n)$, which is both a common "misconception" about $O(\cdot)$ being a lower bound (which it is not) as well as an upper bound (which it actually is) amonst programmers. In that case, note the symmetry $$\binom{n}{k} = \binom{n}{n-k}$$ as well as $$\binom{n}{k} \leq \binom{n}{k + 1}$$ for appropriate $k \leq n/2$ implies that $\binom{2n}{n} \geq 2^n / n \in O(2^n)$. Technically, it is not in $\Theta(2^n)$ but it is superpolynomial/exponential by complexity theory definitions, which is what a lot of people mean when they write $\Theta(2^n)$ or $O(2^n)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you want to show that, in fact, $$\binom{n}{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}=\mathop{O}\left(\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}\right),$$ then there is still an easy induction proof that does not need a Stirling formula. Namely, prove by induction that $$\binom{2n}{n}\le\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}$$ and combine it with the fact that $$\binom{2n-1}{n-1}=\frac{1}{2}\binom{2n}{n}.$$

In fact, a very similar estimate could be proved even without induction. Let’s start with the inequality
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{3}{4}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{2n-1}{2n}
<
\frac{2}{3}\cdot \frac{4}{5}\cdot\ldots\cdot \frac{2n}{2n+1}
$$
for $n\ge 1$, easy to see since each factor is increased from the left hand side to the right hand side.

Dividing LHS by RHS, we obtain
$$
\frac{((2n-1)!!)^2(2n+1)}{2^{2n}(n!)^2}< 1.
$$
Now substitute $(2n-1)!!=\dfrac{(2n)!}{2^{n}n!}$ to get
$$
1>\frac{((2n)!)^2(2n+1)}{2^{4n}(n!)^4}=\frac{2n+1}{2^{4n}}\binom{2n}{n}^2,
$$
or, equivalently,
$$
\binom{2n}{n}<\frac{2^{2n}}{\sqrt{2n+1}}.
$$